# Physical page measures not matching with pdf measure tool

Tags: printing, lyx-layouts

Perhaps related to physical printing and not to LaTex. Googling the problem don't come up with any answer addressing the issue. In a hope that maybe someone here had a similar issue and able to solved it.

When US letter sized `pdf` is generated from following code via `LuaTex`, the `pdf measure tool` measures the dimensions of the layout to be pretty accurate. But when the same pdf goes to printer, `(Actual size, US letter, portrait settings)` the printer keeps the vertical measure (of the printed physical page) to be very accurate `(23.1 cm)` but elongates the horizontal measure further by 2mm (i-e `16.7 cm`) instead of 16.5 cm.

So, if a circle is printed on physical page it will look ellipse, but looks circle on pdf file (aspect ratio is lost while printing).

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\overfullrule=1mm
\documentclass[11pt,draftclsnofoot,onecolumn,conference]{IEEEtran} 

\usepackage[showframe,pass]{geometry}

\usepackage[]{layout} 

\usepackage{graphicx} 

\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath} 
\interdisplaylinepenalty=2500

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}
\usepackage{epstopdf}



\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}       

\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage[obeyDraft,colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix}

\usepackage[section]{placeins} % it keeps the figures in the respective section
\usepackage{stackengine}

\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%
    colorlinks = true,
    citecolor=Green4,
    linkcolor  = blue
}
%SPECIAL FONT INITILIZATION


\pagebreak


% *** GRAPHICS RELATED PACKAGES ***
%
\ifCLASSINFOpdf
  % \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
  % declare the path(s) where your graphic files are
  % \graphicspath{{../pdf/}{../jpeg/}}
  % and their extensions so you won't have to specify these with
  % every instance of \includegraphics
  % \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpeg,.png}
\else
  % or other class option (dvipsone, dvipdf, if not using dvips). graphicx
  % will default to the driver specified in the system graphics.cfg if no
  % driver is specified.
  % \usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
  % declare the path(s) where your graphic files are
  % \graphicspath{{../eps/}}
  % and their extensions so you won't have to specify these with
  % every instance of \includegraphics
  % \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps}
\fi
% graphicx was written by David Carlisle and Sebastian Rahtz. It is
% required if you want graphics, photos, etc. graphicx.sty is already
% installed on most LaTeX systems. The latest version and documentation can
% be obtained at: 



% correct bad hyphenation here
\hyphenation{}


\begin{document}

\layout
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your measured textheight is off by 1.60 pt, that is 0.564 mm. Sligtly less for the width.  Remember, the line has a certain width as well and your measuring cannot be accurate enough.

Comment: 1. Yes, slightly off. +- 1 pt is tolerable, to me.
2. Line is nearly of 1 pt in width, so it should not make too much a difference.
3. Do you think aspect ratio is 1:1 in physical print?

Comment: The second image confused me, it has nothing to do ith the question. You have a printer issue, try another one (different manufacturer) to see if the problem persists or if this is related to your printer. Or print from another viewer.

Comment: Yes, I have only a issue with physical print. Just want to confirm that whether it is related to the way pdf (which is good enough) is generated?

Comment: Issue solved. LuaTex generated an accurately measured (geometric) pdf, the problem was with printer. Once a printer is changed from kyocera KM-3050 KX to Xerox WorkCenter 5865, the physical page has dimensions (m.m) exactly as defined by \layout.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved by comments.